# Error with retrieving data from dbpedia

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

Hey guys I've got a problem with my sparql query can anyone help me.

```
String queryString = 
 "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
 "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
 "PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>"+
 "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"+
 "PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
 "PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+
 "SELECT "+ 
 "?description "+
 "FROM <http://dbpedia.org/page/Arctic_Monkeys> "+
"WHERE " +
"{"+
"?x foaf:depiction ?description."+
"}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    //initializing queryExecution factory with remote service.
    QueryExecution qexec=QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
    //query execution and result processing
    try {
        //simple select
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    }
    finally{
        qexec.close();
    }
}
```

It doesn't retrieve the data needed from dbpedia.
I want to retrieve the data from one specific dbpedia page

Comment: What is it returning that doesnt work?

Comment: It only returns a tittle description but not he actual data form dbpedia

Comment: By "title description", what exactly do you mean?  You can run SPARQL queries against DBPedia at the [online endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) (which I suggest you use to test queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the wrong IRI for identifying the page.  It's not `page`, but `resource`.  Additionally, it's a resource in the graph, not (as far as I know) a named, graph, so you don't need the `FROM` in your query.  Here's a query that works:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?depiction
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Arctic_Monkeys> foaf:depiction ?depiction
}
```

The [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+type%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+prop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+foaf%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fdepiction%0D%0A++++WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FArctic_Monkeys%3E+foaf%3Adepiction+%3Fdepiction%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) have one row, a photo of the Arctic Monkeys playing at MSG.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I haven't used DBPedia much, but I like what it's doing.  There have been a bunch of questions about it lately, and I'm glad to see that people are making use of it.